# How to alter `pseudo` style values in JavaScript dynamic?

Tags: javascript, css

I can able to get the value like this:

```
const childStyle = window.getComputedStyle(child, '::before');
const left = childStyle.getPropertyValue('left');
```

but while I try to alter like this:

```
  const childStyle = window.getComputedStyle(child, '::before');
  const left = childStyle.getPropertyValue('left');
  childStyle.setProperty('left', '0'); //setting not works
  console.log('childStyle', left);
```

getting an error as:

> ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setProperty' on 'CSSStyleDeclaration': These styles are computed, and therefore the 'left' property is read-only

what is the correct way to alter the value of `left` here? please help me.

Comment: Have you tried `element.style.left`?

Comment: this is not for element, it's for elements psudo.

Comment: `getComputedStyle` returns readonly styles of an element. So mutation will not be possible. You can try to fetch elements and then set property.

Comment: how to get elements 'after` `before` element from JavaScript?

Comment: I found this: `":after" is a pseudo element, not an element. You can not return a dom node, it isn't one - all you can do it get the styles`